# Method executing on undefined result (from method with promises to resolve)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-promise

This could be (and probably is) a simple question, but I'm really confused with how to handle promises. I've been reading a lot about it, but still can't completely get it. I'm working with Typescript and Angular and I'm requesting data from an API REST. I have a method getServices, which returns an array with the information I get from the API.

My problem is when I call this method here:

```
this.getServices = (query) => {
            return this.source.getServices(query)
            .then(this.transformToSegments(false));
        };
```

I'm having an error TypeError: results is undefined.

results is used by transformToSegments. I put a lot of console.log() to debug and I saw that transformToSegments is executing before getServices gets resolved, so it tries to work on an undefined result. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I haven't been able to fix it. 
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Julia

Comment: I found this article very helpful when I was trying to wrap my head around Promises in javascript: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: @BrileyHooper yeah thats a good one!

Comment: @BrileyHooper that's great! It's indeed really helpful, I have to say I'm doing (in the process of fixing) a lot of the rookie mistakes :$ Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake. You are passing the result of `this.transformToSegments(false)` to the `.then()` callback. I assume you want something more like:

```
.then(results => this.transformToSegments(false, results))
```

This will delay the execution of the transform until the `then` is called.